# Save and load Ink Canvas StrokeCollection to/from stream

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, inkcanvas

I'm trying to serialize an ink canvas in WPF. So I'm using `StrokeCollection.Save` to save the strokes to a `MemoryStream`. But when I try to load the stream into the `InkCanvas` I get an `ArgumentException` stating "The length of the ISF data must be greater than zero."
Here's the code sample:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    inkcanvas.Strokes.Save(ms);
    inkcanvas.Strokes = new System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection(ms);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check the [`Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.position.aspx) of the your stream?

I think that after saving the stroke into it it will point to the end of it.
Try to reset the position to the first character, like this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    inkcanvas.Strokes.Save(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    inkcanvas.Strokes = new System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection(ms);
}
```